# Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi

Tags: pip, sqlite

I am quite new to this so these type of errors just leave me blank..

I saw another question in which the answer is, do `sudo apt install sqlite3`. I tried  that and the error message says I need to download the 'Java Developer's Kit', not sure if I should do it, so I didn't.

here is the full error message:

```
Collecting sqlite3
  Using cached sqlite3-99.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/lz/hr6sng095hbcsl8b3y9837zc0000gn/T/pip-build-F33eXV/sqlite3/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi")
RuntimeError: Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lz/hr6sng095hbcsl8b3y9837zc0000gn/T/pip-build-F33eXV/sqlite3/
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the command you're running? I don't see how installing `sqlite3` package could produce such output, since it has no relationship with Python or Java (it's written in C).

Comment: Dmitry is correct.  As of this writing, the dependencies for Raspbian Jessie sqlite3 3.8.7.1-1+deb8u2 are:  libc6 (>= 2.4), libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.7.1-1+deb8u2), and libtinfo5.

Comment: The command I run is, `pip install sqlite3`

Answer (score 1):

I searched for *Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi* using DuckDuckGo and found this solution from [a-team systems](https://www.ateamsystems.com/tech-blog/solved-virtualenv-runtimeerror-package-sqlite-must-not-downloaded-pypi/):

> The good news is there is an easy work around: enable your virtualenv
>   to use the system’s (global) site pacakges. This is disabled by
>   default and needs to be enabled when creating the virtualenv via:
>
> `virtualenv --system-site-packages venvdir`
>
> You then simply install the
>   sqlite pip package globally either via pip outside of the virtualenv
>   or via your systems package manager. Once this is done it will work
>   inside the virtualenv as well!

Answer (score 0):

The command you have in your initial post is "sudo apt install sqlite3".

NOTE "apt".

I think what you really meant (and need to use) is "sudo apt-get install sqlite3".

NOTE "apt-get".

"apt-get" being Advanced Packaging Tool on Debian Linux.

"apt" by itself, I'll assume is trying to run the Java Annotation Processing Tool, which accounts for your message about needing to install a JDK.

===========
Update: Come to find out, as explained by Dmitry (thanks!), apt should have worked by itself (without -get) and is a newer front-end to Advanced Packaging Tool. Here is some [more info](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/) on that, specifically. OP must have been in exactly the right directory to stumble into a half-baked Java command.

===========

Incidentally, before running the correct apt-get command, you should probably run "sudo apt-get update". Some more knowledgeable Linux people might correct me, but I think this updates the package list that will be used by your apt-get install command to make sure it downloads the right parts from the right places. I've been playing with the RPi for a couple years and I've gotten into the habit of doing sudo apt-get update before I install packages or upgrade, which is not to say it's a good habit!

Comment: Actually, [`apt`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-apt-get) is a legit command which behaves like a frontend to `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. I can run `sudo apt install sqlite3` just fine. Not sure how the OP got this Java Annotation Processing Tool, which seems to be deprecated and AFAIK not even included in Jessie.